Why is a comment that alleges without substantiating shown but the responses to it are deleted?
User Dottard commented on my answer to the question "Does the"Lord" in the Gospels predominantly refer to Jesus, except for when the O.T. is in view"?
Here's Dottard's comment.
As your answer itself points out, this answer is from JW sources and not the Bible. As I have previously documented, there are many prayers to Jesus in the NT. Thus not only is this answer not from Bible sources, it is also unbiblical. –
Dottard
Apr 29 at 7:14
Was it not deleted because the moderator considered it proper, even though it was an allegation without substantiation? Is a comment like this allowed so it can serve as a good example and to encourage other users to do the same?

It would be helpful if you could clarify your statement The obvious absence of people praying to Jesus in the bible is evident . The answer from @Anne deals strongly with this and comes to the opposite conclusion.. One possibility is the matter of reference to different sources, which ought to be highlighted in both questions and answers.

@NigelJ. The verses used to say that people prayed to Jesus, when examined doesn't not carry the idea that they really prayed to Jesus, which is not in accordance to how Jesus taught them how to pray.. If Jesus is the Hearer of prayer, true followers of God would be praying only to Him. He himself prayed, like he instructed. How many prohets and apostles prayed to Jesus? Shouldn't all be praying to him if he is the Hearer of prayer?

You are clearly struggling in an effort to deny what is plainly on the pages of the KJV.

@NigelJ. It will be helpful if you make plain what is plainly on the pages of the KJV which you say I am clearly struggling in my efforts to deny.

Please see @Anne 's answer which is very clear and well substantiated. Link.

This answer is simply a response from having looked at the temporarily frozen answer of the OP, and the comment from Dottard that was retained, much to the objection of the OP.
The OP said in his temporarily frozen answer:

It was the Father who was adding to their number, as supported by,
(taken from jw.org)


The reference work Exegetical Dictionary of the
New Testament, 1991, (Vol. 2, pp. 329-330) lists Acts 2:47 as a verse
where Kyʹri·os is “used of Yahweh.”


The Companion Bible, with notes
by E. W. Bullinger, 1999 printing, in Appendix 98, “Divine Names and
Titles in New Testament,” lists Acts 2:47 on page 143, under the
heading “LORD . . . Used of Jehovah.”

However, the OP did not give the link. It took me some time to find it from the official jw.org site.
https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1001079344?q=bullinger+companion+bible&p=par
It is important to give webpage links, or book details, when quoting in answers, and to enclose the actual quotes with inverted commas at start and end, and to indent them.
This means that when the OP objects that Dottards’ comment “was an allegation without substantiation”, that is not the case with the first part of it. The OP said he was using the official JW web-source, and I have given the link proving that. Answers need to cite their sources (which was not properly done by the OP) but comments are not answers and do not need to cite sources; that’s only for answers.
However, the last part of Dottard's comment was not accurate when it claimed the OP had not answered from the Bible. The answer was full of Bible quotes. Their interpretation given by the OP could be considered “unbiblical” (the middle part of Dottard’s comment), but comments is not the place for taking that to task. To accuse anyone of giving an unbiblical answer is inflammatory unless stated in an answer with proofs following. Comments is not the place for that.
Whatever the OPs response in comments was, the Moderators involved will know, and they will have their reasons for not keeping that in. But certainly, there are some grounds for the OP objecting to that retained comment, in my view.
